# Filter Search through NSArray by letter not working. IOS

Tags: ios, ios7, nsarray, nspredicate

I am trying to filter / search through an `NSArray` with the text from my `UITextfeild.text`
If I try to search a match string the filter works but my filtered array always comes out empty as I type the letters in the text-field.

```
NSArray *testArray  = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"testmailone@test.com",@"a@test.com",@"b@testing.com",@"h@fgdfgd",@"helloMan@test.com", @"dfsdfsdfsdfsdfs@dsfdfs",nil];
NSPredicate *predicatedString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@", self.addHungryPersonTF.text];
NSArray *resultsArrayString = [testArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicatedString];
NSLog(@"resultsArrayString%@",resultsArrayString);
```

This returns null but if I change the string to match against another set string like so:

```
NSString *matches = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testmailone@test.com"];

NSLog
resultsArrayString(
"testmailone@test.com"
)
```

It then works an the array becomes populated with matched string.

Anyone have any ideas of why it will not search through my `NSArray` by letter? When I type it should be checking the array correctly?

Comment: Maybe trying with `LIKE` instead of `==` in your predicate.

Comment: Your sample code does not even compile. Please provide real code and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *predicatedString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS %@", self.addHungryPersonTF.text];
//keep this one for get all the strings which contains the substring or string itself

   NSPredicate *predicatedString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINS %@", self.addHungryPersonTF.text];
//keep this one for sting starts with the key word
```